# Sending Authorization Token Bearer through JQuery Ajax - Back end is .NET Core Web Api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-ajax

I am having a `401` error code when I access to the api using Jquery Ajax.
This is my front-end code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        debugger

        let payLoad = JSON.stringify({
          Username: $("#username").val(),
          Password: $("#password").val()
        });
        console.log(payLoad)
        $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://localhost:44342/api/Authenticate/login",
          data: payLoad,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
            console.log('ok')
            debugger
            if (result != "Error") {
              console.log('Authenticated');
              CallAPI(result);
            } else {
              console.log('Invalid username or password');
            }
          },
          error: function(req, status, error) {
            debugger
            alert(error);
          }
        });
      });


      function CallAPI(token) {
        debugger
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://localhost:44342/api/Customers',
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
          },
          contentType: "application/json",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result)
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        })
      }
```

For my back-end, I am using ASP.NET Identity

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );

            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }

[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public CustomersController(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Customers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Customer>>> GetCustomer()
    {
        return await _context.Customer.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

and my startup.cs code is

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        // For Identity
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Adding Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        // Adding Jwt Bearer
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
            };
        });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

I have tested. Without `[Authorize]` attribute, I can see the result response at the client side. But once I have added `[Authorize]` attribute and added `headers` property in `CallAPI`  method, it hits `401`. I have tested `https://localhost:44342/api/Authenticate/login` and it works as expected. It returns the token. But when I use the token to call 'https://localhost:44342/api/Customers', it hits `401`

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of registering/configuring authentication and authorization service within startup class?

Comment: @FeiHan I have added some relevant code for startup.cs

Comment: Please try to explicitly apply `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on action method to specify the authentication scheme(s) to use, then check if it can work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But once I have added [Authorize] attribute and added headers property in CallAPI method, it hits 401.

Based on the code of `Startup.cs` that you shared, we can find that you configured multiple authentication mechanisms in your project.

As we discussed in comments, we can specify the authentication scheme (or schemes) with the `[Authorize]` attribute they depend on to authenticate the user.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

For more information about selecting the scheme with the Authorize attribute, please check this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute